# Не проходит соединение

Tags: c, linux, unix, сокет

Кусок кода создает сокет по определенному пути, должен туда записать определенные данные, которые в последствии будут эмулировать устройство bluetooth, с которого должны поступать данные.

Просьба помочь с подключением, почему-то не коннектится.
Ну и критику по поводу кода хотелось бы услышать.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
json_t *SearchBT();
int ConnectionDev();
void AutoInputPK();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (SearchBT()==NULL)
    {
      int res,cl;
      char chr = 'A';
      unsigned    int   sock;
      struct sockaddr_un srvr;
      int len;
        sock = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        srvr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(srvr.sun_path, "/tmp/dataFaros");
        unlink(srvr.sun_path);
        len = strlen(srvr.sun_path) + sizeof(srvr.sun_family);
        bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&srvr, len);
        len = sizeof(srvr);
        res=connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&srvr, len);
           if (res == -1) 
            {
              perror("oops : ");
              exit(1);
            }
        if ( (cl = accept(sock, NULL, NULL)) == -1) 
         {
           perror("accept error");
         }

         write(sock, &chr, 1);
         //read(sock, &chr, 1);
         // printf("char = %c\n", chr);
         close(sock);
         exit(0);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то странно Вы тут накрутили в одной программе и connect и accept на один и тот же сокет.

Так работать не будет.

--

В клиентской части (connect) выбросьте unlink и accept.

В другой программе (серверной) уберите connect, добавьте listen перед accept и замените write на `read(cl, &chr, 1);`

Потом запустите сначала сервер, а потом (в др. окошке) клиент.